# Postgresql : How to display an additional column after an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate-functions, min

I have two tables : users and sessions.

users has columns : username, id

sessions has columns : userid, lastactivityat, deleteat

I wish to extract all the users with the most recent "last activity date" session for each user and then filter the users with a "last activity date" older than x days.
The "last activity date" is in epoch format and ms that's why I had to do some conversion calculation.

Here's my current request (with x = 30)

```
select u.username, min(extract(epoch from now() - to_timestamp(lastactivityat/1000))/86400::int) as most_recent_inactivity_days 
from users as u 
  join sessions as s on s.userid=u.id 
where extract(epoch from now() - to_timestamp(lastactivityat/1000))/86400::int >= 30 
group by username 
order by username
```

Now I wish to add to the result of my request : the deleteat column of each user but I failed with this request :

```
select u.username, min(extract(epoch from now() - to_timestamp(lastactivityat/1000))/86400::int) as most_recent_inactivity_days, s.deleteat  
from users as u 
  join sessions as s on s.userid=u.id 
where extract(epoch from now() - to_timestamp(lastactivityat/1000))/86400::int >= 30 
group by username 
order by username
```

Would you please advise?

Answer (score 0):

This is a case for `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u.username)
       u.username,
       extract(epoch from now() - to_timestamp(lastactivityat/1000))/86400::int AS most_recent_inactivity_days,
       s.deleteat  
FROM users AS u 
   JOIN sessions AS s ON s.userid=u.id 
WHERE extract(epoch from now() - to_timestamp(lastactivityat/1000))/86400::int >= 30
ORDER BY u.username,
         extract(epoch from now() - to_timestamp(lastactivityat/1000))/86400::int;
```

This nice query also shows why it is better to save timestamps as timestamps rather than integers; the query would be so much simpler that way.